# How to Search Multiple Values from single cell

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

In screenshot you can see the Formula and my tables.

As per current formula if you enter "51035" in `C4`, the Description field in `D4` automatically result "Deformed Steel Bar 10MM", (I created another sheet for the code, description and other related things).

Now I want that if I enter "51030" in `C4`, the result in description is shows "Deformed Steel Bar 10MM" but also if I enter 10MM instead of 51030 in `C4`, I want the same result.

I can use this formula

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("51030",C4)),(Value!$F$4),

IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("10MM",C4)),(Value!$F$4)

))
```

But I want a single line formula instead of 2 different lines.

[image: Screen Shot of my Sheet]

Comment: Please describe the desired result and explain the business logic that leads to that result. Posting formulas that DON'T work does not really help. [edit] your question to provide these details, then post a comment to alert the followers of this question.

Comment: Does this other sheet (we can't see) have 10MM etc in it as a separate field or are you expecting to partial match on the description field? Can there be more than 1 item with 10MM? This feels a little error prone without more explanation and data.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understood correctly but if your aim is to convert your formula to a single `IF` formula, then you may use `OR` keyword:

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("51030",C4)), ISNUMBER(SEARCH("10MM",C4))),(Value!$F$4), "Not Found")
```

`OR` keyword takes multiple parameters inside and if one of them is `TRUE` then `OR` statement returns a `TRUE`. And in your case, when one of the criteria are `TRUE`, `IF` statement returns `$F$4` value from the **Sheet:Value**.

Answer (score 0):

Weel, I did it this way with INDEX() and MATCH() faking up some data as per the image.
Enter either 10mm or 12mm or 51030 etc will give the result. Only works for the values that exist - the error function will show "error" if nothing matches.
[image: index match example]